# Simple electrical circuit won't work

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, npn, 7805

Simple NPN switching circuit to open a relay circuit, first NPN switching part didn't want to work (3rd PCB and endless times of trying).

Circuit wizard diagrams, I split its first part to figure out the problem, then removed the push button to ease it even more:

[image]

(Note top view of components below has been photographically mirrored)
[image]

[image]

Solution by @ Andy aka: I had short circuit at all resistances.

Comment: Does your regulator heat up when the relay is not energized?  A regulator like that is simply a controlled power resistor, so if the relay draws moderate current dropping that current through a resistor from 9v to 5v will produce substantial heat.  You can add a heatsink to the regulator package (it is designed with that in mind) but it would be better to use a battery voltage appropriate to the relay and skip the regulator. Also, a 9v "transistor" battery is a poor choice for this, as it will have a short lifetime.

Comment: The fuzzy photos don't help. Are your schematics correct, and which one did you actually construct? Is the relay part of the circuit when the regulator overheats?

Comment: Additionally, that regulator requires a small capacitor across its output, and possibly across its input as well, in order to function properly.  Leaving that out can lead to instability, or even outright wrong voltage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton at this new pcb i didn't even add the relay, it's just what you can see there

Comment: @JoeHass im sorry i would try to get better photos, i got 5v after the regulator so i guess it's not the issue here, what i construct is the first part without the push button

Comment: No, you misunderstood my comment. We don't want to see your photos, we want to see an accurate schematic.

Comment: Do you have any paths from the regulator output to ground, other than through the 1K base resistor or the 300 ohm LED resistor?  Does the transistor get warm?  Add the missing filter caps, then try breaking those paths one by one and see which stops the heating.  Is your regulator in backwards?

Comment: Also, you should put a diode across the relay coil, reverse polarity of the LED. My guess it it's simply heating up because you have a low resistance relay coil. What is that resistance?

Comment: im sorry for the old picture, here is better ones with hd quality

Comment: It's probably the photo but the tracks don't look like they're cut beneath the resistors.

Comment: @Andyaka it's just the rest of untrimmed terminal, not really touching the other track (just plan illusion)

Comment: If you say so!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Shouldn't the tracks be cut under the resistors: -

[image]

I've put a label on the picture but the track doesn't seem to be cut anywhere. Maybe it's my eyes?

Comment: no it's one long tracks along the pcb

Comment: Have you cut tracks anywhere?

Comment: no, here is how it looks like http://www.rtc-electronics.com.kw/images/P/69-4-PCB64145.jpg

Comment: Then the copper tracks are shorting out the resistors dude. You need to cut tracks beneath resistors that have both pins on one track.

Comment: @AndrewxXx: He isn't saying "shouldn't it have come from the factory cut already?", he's saying "why haven't you cut the tracks so that the board matches the schematic?".

Comment: @Andyaka im so sorry i misunderstood that, yes that is right, im so dumb, im really sorry for wasting your time guys, that is so right

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes that's right, i misunderstood that, sorry

Comment: @AndrewxXx If you want to avoid cutting tracks then you can place the components vertically, from one strip(track) to the other and each track represent a node.

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious stuff is the hardest to see.

Answer (score 1):

Regulator looks mirrored on the photo.

Comment: That looks like a good observation to me +1

Comment: i did try to reverse it even that i know it should be like this from the data sheet but ill try to reverse it again, here is how it is now http://www.resistorworld.com.au/image/cache/data/4e73_1-500x500.jpg and it output 300 hfe like in the datasheet on the avo, but ill try that "again"

Comment: That is a transistor... Not the regulator

Comment: There you go: www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf‎

Comment: But the text looks mirrored on the photo, too.  In the original picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/i5412.jpg  neither the regulator nor the text was mirrored.  So I don't think this is it.

Comment: im sorry but no it's not mirrored, however i did try to change it for the sake of argument and still didn't work out

Comment: @AndrewxXx you did post a flipped photo without indicating it as such, which is bound to confuse.